# How to iterate through each JSON object and hit the API?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

My code converts an Excel file into a JSON file and then the JSON file hits the API to create requests in my application.

My JSON output looks like this:

```json
{
   "data": [
      {
         "requestedStart": "2018-11-16",
         "requestedComplete": "2018-11-18",
         "location": "Test",
         "equipment": "Test",
         "switchID": 1
      },
      {
         "requestedStart": "2018-11-23",
         "requestedComplete": "2018-11-25",
         "location": "Test",
         "equipment": "Test",
         "switchID": 1
      }
   ]
}
```

My code:

```python
def json_from_excel():
    excel_file = 'test.xlsx'
    jsonfile = open('ExceltoJSON.json', 'w')
    data = []
    loaddata = OrderedDict()
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('testExceldata')
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

    for j in range(0, 6):
        for i in range(1, 4):         
            temp = {}
            temp["requestedStart"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
            temp["requestedComplete"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 1))
            temp["location"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 2))           
            temp["equipment"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 3))         
            temp["switchID"] = (sheet.cell_value(i, 4))
            data.append(temp)
            loaddata['data'] = data
        json.dump(loaddata, jsonfile, indent=3, sort_keys=False)
        jsonfile.write('\n')
        return loaddata

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = json_from_excel()
    AUTH_HEADERS = {
        'Token': '5ab15b5a66',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
    s = requests.session()
    s.headers = AUTH_HEADERS
    data = json.dumps(dict(data))
    print (data)
    url = 'https://myurl/external/api/v1/Request'
    result = s.post(url, data=data, verify=False)
    print(result.text)
    s.close()
```

But my API can accept only one object at a time. So I want to create a loop such that, the program will take the first object, i.e.

```json
  {
     "requestedStart": "2018-11-16",
     "requestedComplete": "2018-11-18",
     "location": "Test",
     "equipment": "Test",
     "switchID": 1
  }
```

and hit the API to create request and come back to take the second object and hit the API, and so on.

How do I create such a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just easily iterate over that array of data you have:

```
# data = json.dumps(dict(data)) -- this is not needed
url = 'https://myurl/external/api/v1/Request'
for post_data in data['data']:
    result = s.post(url, json=post_data, verify=False)
    print(result.text)
s.close()
```

When you use `session.post()` it can behave multiple ways, [see the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

- `data` is a dictionary: POST form-encoded data. This is used with HTTP forms
- `data` is a string: POST with data encoded by you, headers must be set accordingly
- `json` is a dictionary: POST with JSON data with `application/json` automatically set

This means you can also do `data=json.dumps(data)` to send it as a JSON, but I suggest to use the `json` parameter.

Comment: I tried this. But the data output is coming in single quotes.
{'requestedStart': '2018-11-16T08:00:00Z', 'requestedComplete': '2018-11-18T17:00:00Z', 'location': 'TAWAU', 'equipment': 'GT2', 'switchOrderTypeID': 1}
 Because of this, it's not hitting the api. I need it in double quotes.

Comment: it is printed in single quotes, because that is the default interpretation of strings in python. It has nothing to do with how your request is sent. What is exactly in your response?

Comment: The problem here is in the line data = json.dumps(dict(data)) . While using this line in the original code, I am getting the data in double quotes which hits the api. But the solution which you said(since you said to remove the data=json.dumps), it is printing the output with single quotes. But if i use the line data=json.dumps along with your soluton, I am getting this Type error "String indices must be integers"

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I assumed you need form-encoded values, but I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked perfectly. Thanks for the valuable suggestion :)